# How can I disable certain options with Select2 and remote data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

Select2 supports disabled options when it is initialized on a `<select>` tag, as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/pull/480)

However, I can't find how to achieve the same result with remote data.
Do I need to use a custom format function? How do I prevent the user from selecting it then?
Or is this built-in somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Select2 3.4.2 you just need to add a `disabled: true` property to the given result object. Practical example with a `query` function:

```
$('input').select2({
    query: function(query) {
        //do ajax call which retrieves the results array in this format:
        var data = {results: [
            { id: 1, text: 'disabled option', disabled: true },
            { id: 1, text: 'hi' }
        ]};
        //pass it to the query callback inside your Ajax callback:
        query.callback(data);
    }
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Anvfq/78/)

---

The same can be done using the `ajax` wrapper, which accepts a result objects array in the same format as the `query` function.

Here's a demo with an actual Ajax call (through jsFiddle's JSON API):

```
$('input').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '/echo/json/',
        dataType: 'json',
        params: {
            method: 'post'
        },
        data: function (term, page) {
            // Data to be sent to the server. Usually it is just the "term"
            // parameter (and page if using pagination).
            // However, since this API simply echoes back what we send,
            // I'll build the results array here
            var resultsArr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                resultsArr.push({
                    id: i,
                    text: 'opt'+i,
                    //randomly disable a couple options for demo purposes
                    disabled: Math.random() < .3
                });
            }
            return {
                json: JSON.stringify(resultsArr)
            }
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            //data param === received response from the server. As dataType
            //is json, jQuery automatically parses the response into an object.
            //So, in this case, we received the resultsArr that we sent.
            //Now return it in the correct format: { results: resultsArr }
            return { results: data };
        }
    }
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Anvfq/79/)

Remember that the `data` function in this last example is just to properly use the jsFiddle API - you should keep your original `data` function which sends the query term. All you have to do is modify the response so that the result objects include a `disabled: true` property in the results that you want to be disabled, in the same format as the first example.

Comment: Will try this out first thing tomorrow! Good gosh, if that really works I can't believe it was that simple. Can I just ask one question: how did you know to add this "disabled" property? Did you find this in the docs, or was it an educated guess?

Comment: @Moeri No problem. `=]` I contribute to the Select2 project every now and then, so I'm rather familiarized with its source - it was easy to find where it checks for the disabled property ([here](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/c4529b8700fb1cc2de5e06b9177147581e0e69d5/select2.js#L862)). But you're right, this option is kinda hidden, I'll send a PR to update the docs later today. `:P`

Comment: Alright thanks! I can't award my bounty yet (2 hours remaining) and it's getting late where I live, so you should be getting that first thing tomorrow as well. Thanks for the answer! While it's really simple, I love how you wrote out entire examples. You earned the bounty for sure. :-)

Comment: Okay no rush, g'night. `=]` I've contacted Igor through your GH issue, I'll send a doc update pull request once I manage to document it properly.

Comment: BTW I've made a [PR](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/pull/1629) to document this but had no reply yet.

Comment: @Dementic External resources are pretty much expected to rot away, that is why answers include all the relevant code. Anyway, I've fixed the fiddles, thanks for reporting.

Comment: also, the `selected` prop is work with `disabled` for default display, just like the `option` html tag

Answer (score 3):

select2 can't change the server data, but you can change options
before the result reloaded to the page

```js
  $('.input-selector').select2({
  ajax: {
      url: function (params) {
        return '/to/url/resource.json';
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        var data_modified = $.map(data.results, function (obj) {
          obj.disabled = true; // or use logical statement
          return obj;
        });

        return { results: data_modified };
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks... I didn't find this on documentation.

Comment: sure. with my pleasure